# Как записать значение переменной в память регистра для передачи по протоколу modbus TCP?

Tags: python, tcp, modbus

Я только начинаю разбираться с протоколами передачи данных и столкнулся с трудностями передачи значений переменных. Необходимо смоделировать работу датчиков и их значений, а затем передать на RPi по протоколу Modbus TCP. Для работы использую библиотеку modbus_tk, возможно ли записать значение, полученное в переменной value в регистр временного хранения (Holding Registers)? Возможно его нужно дополнительно перевести в двоичную систему?

```
value = random.randint(0,100)
```

Comment: set_values в примере это не ваш случай ?            https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/blob/master/examples/rtuslave_example.py

Comment: Возможно мой, но что-то я по-прежнему не понимаю как присвоить целочисленное значение в регистр, а так же как задать длину блока регистров и его начальный адрес, да и вообще - в чем заключается смысл блока?